# Managed metadata refiners are not appearing

Tags: web-part, search, refinement-panel

I have a site collection with many document libraries and document sets.

1. I have created a managed property for each crawled property that I needed in the refiner, 4 out of 5 fields are managed metadata fields.
2. I started a full crawl
3. I changed the Index Accuracy to 500.
4. I changed the categories to display to 20 instead of 6
5. And please see the last lines of the filter definition.
6. I put minthreshold to 1.

year is a calculated column, the rest are metadata fields.
For testing: I went to document libraries and searched for the title, or a metadata field VALUE.

Example: we have a column called Agenda Point Category, and there are many items with the value 3. To be decided.

When I search for the word decided, my logic says that the refiner should appear because I set the minthreshold to 1.

The only one that works is actually year. but it shows like this in the refiner lol 1;string#2011

**Edit:**
I have a few properties that work, but the managed metadata properties are never showing on the refinement panel, I checked on central admin, and they are there, and indeed they show examples.
I read in a blog that if you want to use your own ordering, then in the Title attribute you have to put the metadata property name.  Check the screenshot.
And yes, a full crawl was finished after the properties were created via powershell.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FilterCategories>
  <Category    Title="Result Type"    Description="The file extension of the item"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="5"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="4"    MaxNumberOfFilters="0"    SortBy="Frequency"    SortDirection="Descending"    SortByForMoreFilters="Name"    SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"     ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="FileExtension"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer">
    <CustomFilters MappingType="ValueMapping" DataType="String" ValueReference="Absolute" ShowAllInMore="False">
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Adobe PDF">
        <OriginalValue>pdf</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Email">
        <OriginalValue>eml</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>msg</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>exch</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Excel">
        <OriginalValue>odc</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>ods</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>xls</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>xlsb</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>xlsm</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>xlsx</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Image">
        <OriginalValue>tif</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>tiff</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Lotus Notes">
        <OriginalValue>nsf</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="OneNote">
        <OriginalValue>one</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="PowerPoint">
        <OriginalValue>odp</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>ppt</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>pptm</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>pptx</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Publisher">
        <OriginalValue>pub</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Text">
        <OriginalValue>odt</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>txt</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>url</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>csv</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Visio">
        <OriginalValue>vdw</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vdx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vsd</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vss</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vst</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vsx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>vtx</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Webpage">
        <OriginalValue>ascx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>asp</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>aspx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>htm</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>html</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>jhtml</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>js</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>mht</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>mhtml</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>mspx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>php</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue></OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="XML">
        <OriginalValue>xml</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Word">
        <OriginalValue>doc</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>docm</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>docx</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>dot</OriginalValue>
        <OriginalValue>nws</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Zip">
        <OriginalValue>zip</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
    </CustomFilters>
  </Category>
  <Category    Title="Site"    Description="Which site this document is from"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="5"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="4"    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    SortBy="Frequency"    SortByForMoreFilters="Name"    SortDirection="Descending"    SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="SiteName"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer" />
  <Category    Title="Author"    Description="Use this filter to restrict results authored by a specific author"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="5"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="4"    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    SortBy="Frequency"    SortByForMoreFilters="Name"    SortDirection="Descending"    SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="Author"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer"    />
  <Category    Title="Modified Date"    Description="When the item was last updated"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="5"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="6"    MaxNumberOfFilters="0"    SortBy="Custom"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="Write"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer" >
    <CustomFilters MappingType="RangeMapping" DataType="Date" ValueReference="Relative" ShowAllInMore="False">
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Past 24 Hours">
        <OriginalValue>-1..</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Past Week">
        <OriginalValue>-7..</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Past Month">
        <OriginalValue>-30..</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Past Six Months">
        <OriginalValue>-183..</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Past Year">
        <OriginalValue>-365..</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
      <CustomFilter CustomValue="Earlier">
        <OriginalValue>..-365</OriginalValue>
      </CustomFilter>
    </CustomFilters>
  </Category>
  <Category Title="Managed Metadata Columns"    Description="Managed Metadata Columns"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.TaxonomyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="1"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="5"    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="ows_MetadataFacetInfo"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer" />
  <Category Title="Tags"    Description="All managed metadata of the documents and social tags"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.TaxonomyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="3"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="3"    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="ows_MetadataFacetInfo,popularsocialtags"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer" />
  <Category Title="Year" Description="Date"  Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"  MetadataThreshold="1" NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="7" MaxNumberOfFilters="0" SortBy="Name" SortDirection="Ascending" SortByForMoreFilters="Name" SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Descending" ShowMoreLink="True" MappedProperty="MeetingYear" MoreLinkText="show more" LessLinkText="show fewer">
      <CustomFilters MappingType="ValueMapping" DataType="String" ValueReference="Absolute" ShowAllInMore="False">
                            <CustomFilter CustomValue="2014">
                                            <OriginalValue>string;#2014</OriginalValue>
                            </CustomFilter>
                            <CustomFilter CustomValue="2013">
                                            <OriginalValue>string;#2013</OriginalValue>
                            </CustomFilter>
                            <CustomFilter CustomValue="2012">
                                            <OriginalValue>string;#2012</OriginalValue>
                            </CustomFilter>
                            <CustomFilter CustomValue="2011">
                                            <OriginalValue>string;#2011</OriginalValue>
                            </CustomFilter>                         
            </CustomFilters>
  </Category>
  <Category Title="Meeting Type"    Description="Meeting type"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="1"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="5"    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="MeetingType"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer" />
  <Category Title="Content Type" Description="The content type of the item" Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator" MetadataThreshold="1" NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="4" MaxNumberOfFilters="0" SortBy="Frequency" SortDirection="Descending"  SortByForMoreFilters="Name" SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending" ShowMoreLink="True" MappedProperty="ContentTypeRefinement" MoreLinkText="show more" LessLinkText="show fewer"/>
  <Category Title="AgendaPointCategory"    Description="Agenda Point Category"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.TaxonomyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="1"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="5"    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="ows_MetadataFacetInfo"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer" />
  <Category Title="AgendaPointDecision"    Description="Agenda Point Decision"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.TaxonomyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="1"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="5"    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="ows_MetadataFacetInfo"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer" />
  <Category Title="AgendaPointKeywords"    Description="Agenda Point Keywords"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.TaxonomyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="1"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="5"    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="ows_MetadataFacetInfo"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer" />

  </FilterCategories>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This puzzled me for a while as well but I remember playing around with different settings and I believe this solved it for me:

```
<Category Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator" MappedProperty="MyMappedPropertyName" />
```

So I changed the *type* to **ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator** and used the associated *MappedPropertyName*.

Comment: then msdn documentation is wrong in how to do it, thanks Cameron :)

Answer (score 2):

The title property of your XML entry is very important.

1. Place the following XSL into the XSL property of the refinement panel, to 
   view the raw XML, returned by the search

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 
   <xsl:template match="/"> 
   <xmp><xsl:copy-of select="*"/></xmp> 
   </xsl:template> 
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
2. In the output you'll probably see fields with prefix 'metadata_'. 
   Copy the part after the prefix, because that's the name you need to enter in the title property.

   ```
   <category title="ENTER HERE" ...>
   ```

You also mention that it returns "1;string#2011" - make sure that you created a managed property mapped on the ows_xxx(text) crawled property.

Ow and by the way, be careful with the accurency index being set to 500. It might have impact on the overall performance of your search experience.

Hope this helps...

Comment: the index accuracy set to 500 impacts I suppose the crawling only or does it affect when searching? because I dont see a visual difference when browsing and searching

Comment: It can have an impact when searching also... especially when you search for the first time after the nightly application pool recycle.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the managed property settings?

Have you set the refiner property when you created the managed properties?

[image: Refiner example in FAST]

If not try enabling that by editing the managed property and running a full crawl.